# How do I place in order 3,4 and 5 values based on amount (high-low) php

Tags: php, variables

I started writing this code to determine which value within 3 date of births was the highest. As I got to as far as you can see I realised this was a silly way of doing it. There will at times be 4 values or even 5 values so writing every combination like this is sloppy.

$new_date_year1 etc are pre defined from a html form.
Can someone recommend another way of doing this.

```
$valuename1 = "Tom";
$valuename2 = "Jack";
$valuename3 = "Fred";

if ($amount == "3") {    

    if ($new_date_year1 > $new_date_year2 and $new_date_year1 > $new_date_year3 and $new_date_year2 > $new_date_year3) {    
        $highest_amount = $valuename1;
        $second_amount  = $valuename2;
        $third_amount   = $valuename3;
    }
    
    else if ($new_date_year1 > $new_date_year2 and $new_date_year1 > $new_date_year3 and $new_date_year3 > $new_date_year2) {
        $highest_amount = $valuename1;
        $second_amount  = $valuename3;
        $third_amount   = $valuename2;
    }

}
```

Thanks is advance for any help

Comment: I m not sure where data comes from but if from database the why dont you fetch data in right order at start?

Comment: Store in array the date values as time stamp and sort the srray to get the highest value. This will support any number of values

Comment: its form data, from a previous html file.

Comment: what language is this? Check in the documentation if there is a List object that has a guaranteed order or maybe a HashMap<Position, Object> or so.

Comment: php. apologies for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

just in html form replace variable names from $new_date_year1 into $new_date_year[] etc.

then in php You will have array that is sortable, so:

```
$new_date_year[] = '2015';
$new_date_year[] = '2018';
$new_date_year[] = '2016';
```

You can insert data to the array in this way as well(using  [array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)):

```
// implementing an empty array.
$new_date_year = [];
//using array_push
//you can pass multiple values to the  array for explain it further i will pass  '2015','2016','2018' to the array.
array_push($new_date_year,'2015','2016','2018');
```

After adding the values to the array you can sort the array using [rsort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort) which ,

> sorts an array in reverse order (highest to lowest).

```
rsort($new_date_year);

$highest_amount = $new_date_year[0];
$second_amount = $new_date_year[1];
$third_amount = $new_date_year[2];
```

Comment: Ok that's really exciting.Thank you. So i understand. Why don't i need to define the 0,1,2 in the first part of the php? Also can I define the array value as a variable as well?
eg
$new_date_year[] = $variable;

Comment: 1. Definition the 0,1,2 is less elastic than using arrays because for example they can be sorted. 2. Of course, You can do it like this $new_date_year[] = $variable.

Comment: @Hirumina (thank You) edited my answer, so JackB You see what else is possibile to do with arrays and how sort works

Comment: Absolutely. So helpful. Very grateful. Do i have to use the array_push function? Or was that just to demonstrate? I see its just cleaner. :)

Comment: it only demonstrate, <input> 's in html form could look like this: <input name="new_date_year[]" value="2015" /> <input name="new_date_year[]" value="2018" /> <input name="new_date_year[]" value="2016" /> !!!don't forgot of square brackets

Comment: How would i attach extra data to the array values. So the names would match up with the year....?